# What is the right way of using ''to''?

Tags: grammar

> He is the only one who has the right to **draw** the curtain and **show** this painting to the others.

Is it right to say ***show*** because of ***to***, or I should write ***show***? Is ***to*** is only related to **draw*?

Answer (score 1):

***To*** can be used for both ***draw*** and ***show***, so your sentence is correct. If you wish, you can use "to" in front of ***show***, but it is optional. In this case, I don't think it improves the sentence, so I think your original sentence is better.